# C# implicit conversion to inherited grandparent class

Tags: c#

I have a class `DerivedClass` which is inheriting from `BaseEntity` via `BaseClass`.

```
public class BaseEntity<TKey, TEntity>  
    where TKey : IEquatable<TKey> 
    where TEntity : BaseEntity<TKey, TEntity>, new()
{

}
public class BaseClass : BaseEntity<int, BaseClass> 
{

}
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{

}
```

So far so good, but if I want to use it as generic Parameter in a Service like this

```
public class BaseService<TKey, TEntity>
    where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
    where TEntity : BaseEntity<TEntity>, new()
{

}
public class DerivedService : BaseService<int, DerivedClass>
{

}
```

I get the following error.

The type 'DerivedClass' cannot be used as type parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'BaseService<TKey, TEntity>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'DerivedClass' to 'BaseEntity'.

is there a way to achieve this?

When I try to add this line to `DerivedClass`

```
public static implicit operator BaseEntity<int, DerivedClass>(DerivedClass c) => new BaseEntity<int, DerivedClass>();
```

I get the similar error

The type 'DerivedClass' cannot be used as type parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'BaseEntity<TKey, TEntity>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'DerivedClass' to 'BaseEntity<int, DerivedClass>'.

Thanks!

Comment: `BaseEntity<int, DerivedClass>` is not the same type as `BaseEntity<int, BaseClass>` (the base type for `BaseClass`) so there is no trivial implicit conversion between the two.

Comment: Take a look at [Covariance and contravariance in generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance).